# How can I call an Ad in my main activity only once?

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

I have an simple android app where I want to add an Ad in the main activity. But whenever I move to another activity in the app and go back to the main activity, it calls the Ad again. Is there a way to call the Ad only once while the user is using the app?

Here's the code:

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tabpmnth_xm);

// Create the interstitial.
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx8x/x2xxxxxxxx");

AdRequest aadRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.build();

// Begin loading your interstitial.
interstitial.loadAd(aadRequest);

interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
      public void onAdLoaded(){
           displayInterstitial();
      }
```

});

```
public void displayInterstitial() {
 if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
  interstitial.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Too little information. Put the code you are using.

Comment: I just updated the question and I add the code in it.

Comment: I answered this exact same question like a day or two, same wording and everything. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30823721/3508192

Comment: I saw it but didn't quite get it. Let's say the app is a calculator. Do I create a class called Calculator extends MainActivity?

Comment: @Alain: If you don't get an answer you can ask about it in the comments section. Please don't ask same question multiple times.